# angular bootstrap datapicker is not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Hello all I am trying to implement **ui bootstrap datapicker**, to implement month picker (i.e. only year and month should be selected), I have done something by looking various questions here and tutorials, but I am unable to find a solution. can anybody help me to get rid of this, I am providing the code I have implemented.

**NOTE: I am using angular js mvc structure**

**jsp code**

```
 <input uib-datepicker 
                             class="form-control"
                             id="timesheetMonth"
                             is-open="{{opened}}"
                             placeholder="Select Month Year"
                             datepicker-popup="{{mm-yyyy}}"
                             datepicker-options="{minMode: 'month'}"
                             datepicker-mode="'month'"
                             date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
                             data-ng-model="timeSheetMonth"
                             ng-click="reportApp.timesheetMonth = true"
                             close-text="Close"
                                                   />
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question or problem you're facing

Comment: Sorry, But I used the wrong code thats why I was getting wrong output, But now I got what I wanted. And I will close this question. Thanx for the reply.